# VBA Split an Excel Sheet into other sheets based on data in Column A

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

The information in the excel sheet can't be shared but I will share a similar looking excel sheet. So I will explain my situation as best as possible. I downloaded a table from the internet and now I want to split it up into different sheets on the same excel file. So I want a macro that will automatically split the file into a new sheet whenever there is information in the A column. I then want the macro to take all of the rows of the information below it and put it in the new sheet until another cell in the A column then I want it to repeat the same process. I am trying to get each new sheet to be labeled with the information in column A and have the same headers that are in sheet 1. I attached the photos since it was frankly hard to explain in words of what I am trying to do. There are over 7000 thousand rows of information and the only thing that will be constant are the headers of the sheet and the words in each cell in Column A. The amount of info that follows each Column A cell is not consistent.

[The original excel format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR51m.png)

[What I am trying to accomplish automatically with the macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7OLh.png)

```
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = 1
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:C1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To lr
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Please add your code if you want help and please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: None of my code has remotely worked. I have a ton of code for logging into the website then clicking the buttons and pulling all the data from the website table. I then have code formatting the data the way I want. I figured that code was useless for this problem but I don't know how to take info from column A and then pull everything after it until another piece of information pops up in column A.

Comment: I added code but it doesn't move the rows with a blank in column A @Miqi180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the new worksheets on the fly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub createClassSheets()
    Dim i As Long, vlr As Long, cls As Range, hdrs As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        hdrs = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value2
        vlr = .Cells.Find(What:=Chr(42), After:=.Cells(1), _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        For Each cls In .Cells(2, "A").Resize(vlr, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
            On Error GoTo createClassSheet
            'Debug.Print .Range(cls.Offset(1, 1), cls.Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Address(0, 0)
            .Range(cls.Offset(1, 1), cls.Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy _
                Destination:=Worksheets(cls.Value2).Cells(3, 2)
        Next cls
    End With

    Exit Sub

createClassSheet:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        With Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            .Name = cls.Value2
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(hdrs, 1), UBound(hdrs, 2)) = hdrs
            .Cells(2, 1) = cls.Value2
            'do other formatting here
        End With
        Resume
    Else
        Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```