# Is there a function that will split repeated values ​into pages with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to split the rows in the Excel sheet into different sheets with reference to column A. For example, it will automatically copy the line with "A3FK" between A2:A5 to newsheet2. The line with "A4FK" between A6:A18 to newsheet3. Like this.

I have a code that divides the page in the number of lines I have given.

How can I edit it to reference the cell value?

```
Sub CutAndPasteToNewPage()

  
Dim one,two As String

    Lines = InputBox("In how many lines: ", "Start", Default)
    First = ActiveSheet.Name
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
 
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        c = i + Lines
        CutArea = "A" + CStr(i) + ":" + "A" + CStr(c)
        ActiveSheet.Range(CutArea).Cut

        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Worksheets(First).Activate
        i = i + Lines
        Next

End Sub
```

Tried to split the page into different pages referencing the data in column A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This** can be done:
Working with the following data set:

[image: DataSet]

We can import the data into some arrays, build few worksheets, and copy the data to them.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitToSheets()
    
    Dim I As Long
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim Yo As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim Master As Worksheet
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim RefList
    Dim Datalist
    Dim OutList
    
    ' > Working with "Master" Sheet
    Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    With Master
    
        ' > Identify how many sheets we need, the last row/column on _
            master sheet, import data into arrays, resize output array _
            larger than required.
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = .Range("ZZ1").End(xlToLeft).Column
        RefList = WorksheetFunction.Unique(.Range("A2:A" & lRow))
        Datalist = .Range("A1").Resize(lRow, lCol)
        ReDim OutList(1 To UBound(Datalist, 1), 1 To UBound(Datalist, 2))
        Yo = 1
        
        ' Cycle Through each Label / New Worksheet
        For I = 1 To UBound(RefList, 1)
            
            ' > Build New Worksheet
            Debug.Print RefList(I, 1)
            Set WS = Worksheets.Add(, Master)
            WS.Name = RefList(I, 1)

            ' > Transfer all related data to array
            For Y = 1 To UBound(Datalist, 1)
                If Datalist(Y, 1) = RefList(I, 1) Or Y = 1 Then
                    For X = 1 To UBound(Datalist, 2)
                        OutList(Yo, X) = Datalist(Y, X)
                    Next X
                    Yo = Yo + 1
                End If
            Next Y

            ' > Output Array to New Worksheet
            WS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(OutList, 1), _
                UBound(OutList, 2)).Value = OutList

            ' > Erase / Reset Array
            For Y = 1 To UBound(OutList, 1)
                For X = 1 To UBound(OutList, 2)
                    OutList(Y, X) = ""
                Next X
            Next Y
            Yo = 1

        Next I
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Which works surprisingly quickly to give us the full data set split between enough sheets for each label:

**Worksheets:**

[image: Label Example]

**Data:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**...**

Comment: Thank you. But it's not working for me. I take many errors. Maybe it didn't work because i did it in another version. But I found this code while searching why your code is not working.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459133/vba-split-an-excel-sheet-into-other-sheets-based-on-data-in-column-a

This code work for me. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, May I ask what type of errors you encountered?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. When I corrected the error line like this, it worked. Thank you for your help.
This was the line that gave the error. <Subscript out of range>

Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

But it worked when i changed it like this
Set Master = ActiveSheet

Thank you again.